# Как сделать обтекание ul li в ряд, без задания ширины для li?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть список ul, для li задано float: left. В li находятся картинки, ширина li не задается. Т.е. li встают в один ряд, ширина li становится равной ширине картинки. Но при первой загрузке картинки не успевают прогрузиться и каждый li встает с новой строки. После этого, если нажать f5, то li уже выравниваются правильно, в ряд.
Как бы решить эту проблему? Не могу задать ширину для li, т.к. все картинки разной ширины.

```
<ul>
  <li><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="1.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>

li {
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: display:inline-block;  ?

Comment: Нет, это ничего не меняет.

Comment: ul {display: flex}

Comment: я имел ввиду для li но без flex для ul , но flex лучше

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="1"></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/300/500" alt="2"></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/700" alt="3"></li>
  <li><img src="https://picsum.photos/150/300" alt="4"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

ul::after { /* fix */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=li 1" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=li 2" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=li 3" alt=""></li>
  <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=li 4" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```